How to express a traceless matrix in Pauli basis
This question is probably too obvious, so sorry beforehand.
We know that the generalized Pauli elements $P\in \mathcal{P}_d \setminus {\mathrm{Id}_d}$ in Sylvesters representation, hence not Hermitian, constitute a basis for $\mathfrak{sl}_d$, the special Lie algebra of dimension $d$, which is a matrix Lie algebra of all traceless matrices with determinant 1.
Now, how would I express a matrix $M$ within this algebra in this basis? The question may be too obvious, but since the trace vanishes for $M$ and $P$ it vanishes for $MP$ too, since $M$ is invertible as well. But the Hilbert Schmidt inner product, which would be the inner product of this space I guess, since it is a sub vector space of the $\mathfrak{gl}_d$, is precisely the trace $Tr(P^\dagger M)$ which should be zero, since $\mathfrak{sl}_d$ should be a $*$-algebra and therefore $P^\dagger$ should also be part of this algebra.
How would i then write $M$ in this basis?

Are you sure the product is traceless?

the HS inner product is non-degenerate, thus it can't vanish on the whole traceless subspace. I'm also not sure why you would think that the product of two traceless matrices is traceless. Just take $M=X$ and $P=X$ as a trivial counter-example
